# SSL Certyficate: Could not bind TCP port 80 AWS Amazon EC2 Linux

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, ssl, amazon-ec2

After running the command 'sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d my_domain.com,' I get the following error:

> Could not bind TCP port 80 because it is already in use by another
> process on this system (such as a web server). Please stop the program
> in question and then try again.

How can I stop port 80 and install SSL or how can I install SSL without causing downtime to the server?
When I access http://my_domain.com, I receive the response 'It works.' I aim to set up SSL only on my backend server and host it on my_domain.com.

I want only to make SSL on my backend server and host it on my_domain.com

===
EDIT
I fix that problem by closing my old apache on :80 port, but my ssl stil not working. After generate ssl i use this commands

> $ sudo su
>
> cd /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain.com
>
> openssl pkcs12 -export -in fullchain.pem -inkey privkey.pem -out
> keystore.p12 -name backend -CAfile chain.pem -caname root
>
> cp keystore.p12 /home/ec2-user/
>
> cd /home/ec2-user/
>
> chown ec2-user keystore.p12
>
> exit.